# Javascript: prompt and conditional

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, prompt

i'm studing Javascript.
I need a suggestion to resolve this problem.

When the answer is B or C I want show the two different Hint.
What is wrong on my code?

```
function whatBring() {
  if (prompt('What brings Little Red Riding Hood in the basket?  A: Food - B: Book - C:Carbon') == 'A') {
       alert('bene, conosci la storia!');
    } else if (prompt(''What brings Little Red Riding Hood in the basket?  A: Food - B: Book - C:Carbon') == 'B'){
       alert('Hint: it's not correct!');
    } else if (prompt(''What brings Little Red Riding Hood in the basket?  A: Food - B: Book - C:Carbon') == 'C'){
       alert('Hint: it's not correct!');
   }
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: The highlighting already offers a hint: Be sure to escape `'` with `\'` where it's needed, e.g. `alert('Hint: it\'s not correct!')`

Comment: Firstly you need to change `''What brings...'` to `'What brings...'`

Comment: Shouldn't the whole thing just be `function whatBring() {if (prompt('What brings Little Red Riding Hood in the basket?  A: Food - B: Book - C:Carbon') == 'A') {alert('bene, conosci la storia!');
} else { alert("Hint: it's not correct!");}
}`

Comment: @j08691: That is what I just answered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem (aside from the syntax errors, see the highlighting in the question) is that you're re-prompting repeatedly.

If you only want to prompt once and then check various values, you have two options:

1. Use `switch`:

   ```
   switch (prompt(/*...*/)) {
       case 'A':
           // alert for A
           break;
       case 'B':
           // alert for B
           break;
       case 'C':
           // alert for C
           break;
       default:
           // alert if it's none of the above
           break;
   }
   ```
2. Remember the value in a variable, and then check the variable:

   ```
   var answer = prompt(/*...*/);
   if (answer === 'A') {
       // alert for A
   }
   else if (answer === 'B') {
       // alert for B
   }
   else if (answer === 'C') {
       // alert for C
   }
   else {
       // alert if it's none of the above
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
function whatBring() 
{
        var response = prompt('What brings Little Red Riding Hood in the basket?  A: Food - B: Book - C:Carbon');

        if (response == 'A') {
              alert('bene, conosci la storia!');
        }
        else  
        {
            // All other responses are incorrect.
             alert('Hint: it's not correct!');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a single prompt call, capture the input to a variable and compare that:

```
function whatBring() {
    var input = prompt('What brings Little Red Riding Hood in the basket?  A: Food - B: Book - C:Carbon') == 'A');

    if (input == "A") {

    } else if (input == "B") {

    } else if (input == "C") {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using three `prompt` calls, so if the first is not correct, it will show another prompt instead of checking the value from one prompt against three different values.

Put the result from the prompt in a variable, so that you can use it in all the conditions:

```
var answer = prompt('What brings Little Red Riding Hood in the basket?  A: Food - B: Book - C:Carbon');

if (answer == 'A') {
  ... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You're prompting 3 times, potentially, based on what the user answers.  You should prompt once and then store the response in a variable, then use that variable to compare in an if-statement.

```
var promptAnswer = prompt("What brings Little Red Riding Hood in the basket?  A: Food - B: Book - C:Carbon");

if (promptAnswer == 'A')
else if (promptAnswer == 'B')
```